# Can I run a java jar program with ssh?

Tags: java, ssh

I want to run a Java program using ssh, I've copied my private keys and I can run simple linux commands.

If run this command from the server I can see all the directories

```
ssh user@192.168.1.2 pwd
```

However I want to run a Java jar app, like this:

```
ssh user@192.168.1.2 java -Djava.library.path=myapp/. classpath=myapp/myapp.jar:. myClass
```

This is how I exactly run my app in the client machine:

```
java -Djava.library.path=myapp/. classpath=myapp/myapp.jar:. myClass
```

I got this error, obviously, java is installed

```
java: command not found
```

Comment: Is java installed? What is the output of this command `java -version`

Comment: Is java installed at the location you think it is?

Comment: Java's not on the path then. Use `ssh user@192.168.1.2 /path/to/java -Djava.lib...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely problem is that the `java` command is not on the command search path for the `user` account.

1. Login to the client machine as `user`, and type `java -version`.  If it says `"command not found"`, that is indisputable evidence that `java` is not on the user's command search path.
2. Login to the client machine using an account that you know can run `java`.  Now run `java -version` to confirm that.  Assuming that it works, run `which java` to find the path for the `java` command.  (If it didn't work, then you are probably wrong about Java being installed.  Or at leats ... about it being installed **correctly**.)
3. On the client machine, work out what the absolute path for the "myapp" directory is.  Check that the "myapp" directory and its contents are readable by "user".
4. From the server, try running the app like this:

   ```
     ssh user@192.168.1.2 /path/to/java \
         -Djava.library.path=/path/to/myapp \
         -classpath /path/to/myapp/myapp.jar myClass
   ```

   Notes:

   - If `java` is not on the user's command search path, use an absolute pathname for the `java` command.  In fact, it is advisable to use an absolute path anyway if you are concerned that the user might "alias" the `java` command to something else.
   - Use absolute paths for the installation of `myapp` ... to avoid problems with the user moving it, replacing it, etcetera.
   - The syntax for the classpath option is different to what you showed us
   - You shouldn't have `.` on the classpath unless your Java app *expects* to be loading additional Java code out of the user's home directory.

---

> Obviously, java is installed ...

Why is it obvious?

How do you know that?  Can you guarantee that for all client machines?  Can you guarantee that "the user" won't mess with things?

Are you sure that Java is installed **correctly**?  For example, that you have installed it in a place where it is on the "default" command search path for the user?

In a situation like this, you need to check / double-check all of your assumptions.  Carefully.  Methodically.  The problem is typically something "face-palm obvious" that you have overlooked.

(It is human to make mistakes ... and counter productive to assume that you don't.)

Comment: Thank you! That worked. As I wrote, java was obviously installed :) I'm just kidding. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Create a shell file and run that file over ssh using the following command:

```
ssh user@host "sh ~/app-start.sh"
```